# Setting an array's value via a function's return value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that values are dynamically obtained from a function(or supposed to be), you may see example below. But looks like it doesn't work as expected. Is this usage wrong ?

```
$products = array(
    "saloon" => array(
        array(
            "id"    => "23544",
            "precise"   => "unkown",
            "pump"  =>  "auto",
            "density"   =>  "5:3",
            "name"      =>  "Multi dose arranger",
            "color"     =>  "224,0,92",
            "desc"      =>  "....",
            "cdate"     =>  "12342315",
            "support"   =>  "#lab"
        )// Goes like this.
      )
    ),

    "basic" => array(
        //Goes on and on
    ),

    "variable"  => array(
    )
);
array(
    2=> array(
        getProduct(16,"everyday"),
        getProduct(24,"everyday")
    ),
    3=> array(
        getProduct(16,"everyday"),
        getProduct(23,"everyday")
    ),
    4=> array(
        getProduct(16,"everyday"),
        getProduct(24,"everyday")
    )
);



function getProduct($id,$cat){
    GLOBAL $products,$a;
//  echo $a;
//  print_r(is_array($products));


    foreach ($products[$cat] as $product) {
        if($product["id"]==$id){
            $selectedProduct = $product;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $selectedProduct;

}
```

function is like above but setts nothing, also printing array is also return empty.

Comment: what is the function ? also what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: You say `it doesn't work as expected` - what is happening??

Comment: just nothing, doesn't sets value.

Comment: Please RTFM what `exit` does. http://php.net/exit

Comment: @deceze thanks for your "kind" response. anyway, I've changed exit with break, but the problem is even print_r($products) is not working but, just calling function outside of array works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function for that:

```
function getProduct($id,$cat){
    global $products,$a;    

    foreach ($products[$cat] as $product) {
        if($product["id"]==$id){
            $selectedProduct = $product;
            break; //Instead of exit
        }
    }
    return $selectedProduct;
}
```

Don't use `exit` because you want to break the execution of the foreach, not exit the program, use `break` instead.

EDIT: Corrected what the exit function does, thanks to @deceze

Comment: `exit` not only "exits the function", it *ends* the whole program.

Comment: My mistake, I've changed exit with break, but print_r($products); doesn't write anything on screen.

Comment: @siniradam Update your answer with the whole code and changes you made

Comment: @siniradam With this example a get dozens of notice because "everyday" is not a valid index.

Comment: If i change the index for "saloon" and the id of the example array from "23544" to "16" then the result is as expected... what's the problem now?

Comment: what the heck, i've found the problem, I don't know how is this happened but appearantly because of some invisible characters, I've just removed array titles and writed again and it worked. I'm really confused. Maybe something related with sublime. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you do wrong is using exit inside your function (it stops the whole script execution). You should change your function into:

```
function getProduct($id,$cat){
    global $products,$a;
//  echo $a;
//  print_r(is_array($products));


    foreach ($products[$cat] as $product) {
        if($product["id"]==$id){
            return $product;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In fact you don't need exit or break because you can simple return `$product` when you find it. You should also return value in case you don't find any product. In above example `false` is returned in that case.